# "most shared on" module on facebook

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I'm working on launching on a website soon which may be categorized as a news source. I have searched everywhere how I can enable this module for my website which scans your domain and automatically generates a list of top 5 shared links from your domain. 
This is a really awesome module to promote such websites.

Does anyone know how this can be enabled ? Is it a paid feature?

Comment: Are you using WordPress CMS or as a blog-site. I know in Joomla you can do this without any changes or extensions.

Comment: Im using wordpress. Please check out the screenshot to clear get the idea what Im talking about:http://s11.postimg.org/ofwfrkujn/Capture.png

Answer (score 0):

There's the [Recommendations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/) plugin, which sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Please see the screenshot at:
http://s11.postimg.org/ofwfrkujn/Capture.png

The recommendations box is different from this. I don't want any plugin for the site. This module is displayed in the news feed of the people who like the facebook page of that website.

Comment: There isn't a way to turn that on, Facebook's algorithms determine whether it's worth showing for your site. Chances are you'll need a fairly large, heavily trafficked site that's getting lots of shares for it to show up. http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/11/28/facebook-module-highlights-popular-links-posted-by-news-sources-users-like/